# Set up G Suite. Adding TXT record

Tags: dns

I follow `Set up G Suite` to verify domain and set up email in G Suite.
I need to add new TXT record for my domain.
The problem is that for the name of TXT record I must add `@`, but when I try I get this error:

> A zone name must be a domain name, and can include a period at the end.

How can I add TXT record to verify my domain for G Suite ?

Comment: Who is your DNS provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@` is a shorthand notation for the "apex domain", or just `example.com` with no subdomain.

For DNS, a *Fully Qualified Domain Name* is generally notated as `example.com.` with a dot at the end.

It seems that your DNS config provider wants you to use `example.com.` instead of the shorthand `@`.

Comment: Thanks, @stephen-ostermiller, I forget to use proper fake domains sometimes.